# AAD: preventing account picker

Tags: azure-active-directory

is there any way (OIDC auth request parameter) that I could use to prevent AAD from doing account discovery when I send the user to my AAD tenant (not /common)? Currently, AAD displays a page asking for the user email (I presume in case the user is a B2B user in my directory) and only then sends the user to my ADFS (my federation service). I would like to be able to have the user only see ADFS.

Comment: I think if you set `domain_hint=yourdomain.com` on the authorization URL, it'll figure out you want to login a user from the federated domain and forward to ADFS.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I already tried it. That's how I get to the AAD login page in the first place. However, AAD does not know at this stage whether I will be using a federated, local (e.g. @abc.onmicrosoft.com) or B2B account (I assume). I am looking at ways to tell AAD the user is federated.

Comment: `domain_hint` works well mostly.. in cases where I've seen it fail, the login url (to /authorize endpoint) was making use of explicit `prompt` parameter with values like `login` or `select_account` which interrupts single sign on.. so that would be my guess for you to check.. If that is the case try removing `prompt` and let me know.. I can answer with a few more details.. If it still doesn't work out please share the detailed URL that gets created for page asking for user email

Comment: Yes, removing prompt= and adding domain_hint= does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

@juunas' suggestion to use domain_hint= parameter and @Rohit's to remove login= parameter did the trick. Thanks!